# Show the heading direction of a compass on a map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, bing-maps, compass-geolocation

I have a Windows Phone application with a map. On this map, there are several pushpins (different infos on the map) and a **pushpin of the current position**. I want to show the **heading direction** (the direction the user looks with his phone) on the current position pushpin (using the **compass** angle). I already have a custom control that rotates according to the compass value. What I don't know is how to incorporate it into the map, i.e. **show it on the current position on the map**.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much.

PS: If you don't know what I mean, I intend to do something like it's available in the (Nokia) Here Maps [image: Here Maps heading direction with compass].

Comment: Most Windows Phone 7 devices don't have a compass, it wasn't a required part of the platform. All WP8 devices do have it though.

Comment: hi @NeilTurner Thank you for the hint - I am aware of this fact. We developed an Augmented Reality app which also doesn't work on a lot of WP7 devices because it misses the compass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer. What I know is you can add any control to a map using this technique:

```
myMap.Layers.Add(new MapLayer()
 {    
    new MapOverlay()
    {
        GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(37.795032,-122.394927),
        Content = new Ellipse
        {
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
            Width = 40,
            Height = 40
        }
    }});
```

This comes from [http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What's_new_in_Windows_Phone_8](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8)

Now this will display a simple red dot, but I understand you can put just about any control in there. Use your control, bind the rotation to a value that will hold the rotation in your view model and I think you are quite done.  Does this work for you?